# wpf: check if all dll's from the references are present

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

Is there a way to programatically check if all the dll's from the reference folder and from other reference projects are present?

Here is a scenario: a guy copy my exe with some dll's and then he deletes one and he wants how the application behaves and I want to prevent this by checking at startup if all dll'd are there and if don't, I will close the application.

Comment: Well, checking just references that are declared in VS references might be not enough: some libraries have dependencies to other libraries, and so on. In VS you only reference the "root" library, not all the dependency tree. The simpliest way I see is to have a list with dll names that you might check in app.xaml.cs. But there is a chanse, that your application will not arive at the point where you could check it, if some crucial libraries are missing(.net framework is not installed)

Comment: but by doing this, every time when I add a new library, I have to change the code and this is not a good solution

Comment: If you are adding a library, you are changing code anyway, otherwise why would you add a library? But yes, it would add you extra  maintenance overhead. On the other hand, getting all dependencies programmatically would cause performance overhead on application startup. So for quite rare scenario when user manually deletes dll you will add unneded performance overhead for every successful launch. I would suggest you to think twice before going with programatical way.